# and who really knows why child window (button) not created or maybe not visible after wm_create message

Tags: windows

```
extern GetModuleHandleA
extern LoadCursorA
extern RegisterClassA
extern CreateWindowExA
extern GetMessageA
extern DispatchMessageA
extern TranslateMessage
extern ExitProcess
extern PostQuitMessage
extern DefWindowProcA

section .data

MSG      dq 0         ;+0 hWnd
dd 0         ;+8 message
dd 0         ;padding for next
wParam dq 0         ;+10 wParam
dq 0         ;+18 lParam
dd 0         ;+20 time
dd 0         ;+24 1st part of point structure
dd 0         ;+28 2nd part of point structure
dd 0         ;padding to bring total size to 48 bytes

WNDCLASS dd 1h+2h+40h ;+0 window class style (CS_VREDRAW+CS_HREDRAW+CS_CLASSDC)
dd 0         ;padding for next
dq WndProcTable       ;+8 pointer to Window Procedure
dd 0         ;+10 no. of extra bytes to allocate after structure
dd 0         ;+14 no. of extra bytes to allocate after window instance
hInst dq 0         ;+18 handle to instance containing window procedure
dq 0         ;+20 handle to the class icon
hCursor dq 0         ;+28 handle to the class cursor
dq 6         ;+30 identifies the class background brush (6=COLOR_WINDOW+1)
dq 0         ;+38 pointer to resource name for class menu
dq win_class_name   ;+40 pointer to string for window class name

win_class_name db 'simplewindow',0     ;string holding name of window class
win_id dq 0  
but_id dq 0
kopf db '64 bit program', 0
class_button db 'button', 0
button_kopf db 'hjh', 0

mbt db 'this is only a test', 0
mbc db 'achtung', 0

section .text

global  start
start:  
sub rsp, 0x8
xor rcx, rcx
call  GetModuleHandleA
mov [hInst], rax
mov rcx, 0
mov rdx, 32512
call LoadCursorA
mov [hCursor], rax  
mov rcx,  WNDCLASS
sub rsp, 0x20
call RegisterClassA
add rsp, 0x20

;creating main window
mov rcx, 0
mov rdx, win_class_name
mov r8, kopf
mov r9, 0x10000000+0x00080000+0x00020000
push 0
push qword[hInst]
push 0
push 0
push 512
push 512
push 256
push 256
sub rsp, 0x20
call CreateWindowExA
add rsp, 0x20
add rsp, 0x40
mov [win_id], rax  

zyklus:
mov rcx, MSG
mov rdx, 0
mov r8, 0
mov r9, 0
sub rsp, 20h  
call GetMessageA
add rsp, 20h
or rax, rax
jz fertig
mov rcx, MSG 
call TranslateMessage  
mov rcx, MSG   
call DispatchMessageA  
jmp zyklus

fertig:
mov rcx,  [wParam]
call ExitProcess

WndProcTable:  
sub rsp, 0x8
cmp edx, 0x01  ; see if it is wm_create  message
jne quit              

; creating button

mov rcx, 0
mov rdx, class_button
mov r8, button_kopf
mov r9, 0x40000000+0x10000000  ; child +visible
push 0
push qword[hInst]
push 0
push qword[win_id]
push 20
push 50
push 30
push 30
sub rsp, 0x20
call CreateWindowExA
add rsp, 0x20
add rsp, 0x40
mov [but_id], rax        
jmp alles

quit:
cmp edx, 0x02
jne weiter

xor rcx, rcx
call PostQuitMessage
weiter:
sub rsp,20h            
call DefWindowProcA
add rsp,20h             

alles:
add rsp, 0x8

ret
```

however if you place the creation button code after creation main window code
everything works fine but it fails while processing wm_create mrssage

nasm -f win64  first.nasm -o first,obj
 golink   first,obj user32.dll kernel32.dll gdi32.dll

the button doesn't appear or may be not created at all
what's wrong?
I want to know what is going wrong with this piece of code
is there anybody who notices any mistake in this code
I don't know where  to find mistakes

now it is solved. the thing is that main window handle is not valid in creating button after wm_create the valid handle is in rcx register (it is passed in wndproctable as the first parameter) so the right line is push rcx

Comment: Maybe parent hwnd is invalid,  maybe hInstance is invalid, maybe... Without detail explanation we are only guess.

Comment: The code is woefully insufficient.  It doesn't appear to check the return value of CreateWindowEx() nor call GetLastError() and report the value.  So you can't know what is wrong.  Using assembly to write winapi code like this is rather an unproductive way to go about it.

Comment: This code violates a whole bunch of calling convention rules. I would recommend learning Win32 with C or C++ first, then learning assembly, then combining the two as a final step. Right now, you need to learn the difference between mov and lea.

Comment: this code works well - window appeared except button

Comment: no convention violation - see goasm examples

Comment: You are not allocating home space when you call GetModuleHandleA. You are modifying the stack pointer and using push instructions outside the prologue or epilogue.

Comment: If you have the answer, please answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it is solved. the thing is that main window handle is not valid in creating button after wm_create the valid handle is in rcx register (it is passed in wndproctable as the first parameter) so the right line is push rcx